# split in two list a txt file python

Tags: python, list, file, text

i need the speedest way to read a txt file and return 2 list.

The file start with some empty rows then there is a n*m table that a need to allocate in a list and then some empty rows and a list of words and every rows may contain 1 or more word separated with spaces

this is what i have done but is to slow in my opinion,probably i'm looking for something with iteration

```
        with open(file) as f:
            sub = ''
            matrix = []
            word = []
            c = 0
            a = False
            for line in f:
                if line == '\n':
                    if c == 1:
                        a = True
                    continue
                if a:
                    l = line.split()
                    for x in l:
                        word.append(x)
                else:
                    sub = line.strip('\n')
                    matrix.append(sub)
                    c = 1
        f.close()
        matrix = [x.upper() for x in matrix]
        word = [x.upper() for x in word]
        return matrix, word
```

an example file should be:
'\n' is a blank row

```
example.txt:
\n
\n
\n
jebvoqbfvqoif
feqbfoeqbfoie
qfenfoeiqnfoi
ejfnqoeifboqe
nefoineoifneo
nfeqiofhneoif
enfqoinfeoifn
fewknfoiewnfn
\n
\n
\n
efwhhewof eiwofoiefw fwnenfif
wefioh
wfeno
ewfioef
oefkofeofo
```

the output should be:

```
list 1:
[
"jebvoqbfvqoif",
"feqbfoeqbfoie",
"qfenfoeiqnfoi",
"ejfnqoeifboqe",
"nefoineoifneo",
"nfeqiofhneoif",
"enfqoinfeoifn",
"fewknfoiewnfn"]
list 2:
[
"efwhhewof",
"eiwofoiefw", 
"fwnenfif",
"wefioh",
"wfeno",
"ewfioef",
"oefkofeofo"]
```

Comment: Does the file actually contain a `\n` on those lines or is that just a literal? In which case please remove all the `\n` and just leave blank lines. Also does the file itself contain `example.txt` at the top? If not please reformat your question to what the file ACTUALLY looks like.

Comment: hi, sorry, the \n means a empty row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is using `itertools.groupby` and `itertools.chain` (The file `sample.txt` contains the text you've stated in question)

For example:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    matrix, words = [[*chain(*map(str.split, g))] for v, g in groupby(map(str.strip, f_in), lambda k: k != '') if v]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(matrix)
pprint(words)
```

Prints:

```
['jebvoqbfvqoif',
 'feqbfoeqbfoie',
 'qfenfoeiqnfoi',
 'ejfnqoeifboqe',
 'nefoineoifneo',
 'nfeqiofhneoif',
 'enfqoinfeoifn',
 'fewknfoiewnfn']
['efwhhewof',
 'eiwofoiefw',
 'fwnenfif',
 'wefioh',
 'wfeno',
 'ewfioef',
 'oefkofeofo']
```

Comment: any other method without using external library?

Comment: @3dvolt Well, `itertools` (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html) is in standard library - it's good to know it. It makes apparently "hard" tasks like these easy.